# Locality of Connection

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a lemma in Lee's Riemannian Geometry:

> Lemma 4.1: Suppose $\nabla$ is a connection in a smooth vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$. For ever $X \in \mathfrak X(M)$, $Y \in \Gamma(M)$, and $p \in M$, the covariant derivative $\nabla_X Y|_p$ depends on the values of $X$ and $Y$ i an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $p$.

> First, consider $Y$. Replacing $Y$ by $Y - \tilde Y$ shows that it suffices to prove $\nabla_X Y|p = 0$ if $Y$ vanishes on a neighborhood of $p$.
> Suppose $Y$ is a smooth section of $E$ that is identically zero on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$. Choose a bump function $\varphi \in C^\infty(M)$ with support in $U$ such that $\varphi(p) = 1$. The hypothesis that $Y$ vanishes on $U$ implies that $\varphi Y \equiv 0$ on all of $M$, so for every $X \in \mathfrak X(M)$, we have $\nabla_X(\varphi Y) = \nabla_X (0 \cdot \varphi Y) = 0$. Thus, the product rule gives
> $$0 = \nabla_X (\varphi Y) = (X \varphi) Y + \varphi(\nabla_X Y).$$
> Now, $Y \equiv 0$ on the support of $\varphi$, so the first term on RHS is identically 0. Evaluating equation above at $p$ shows that $\nabla_X Y |_p = 0$. The argument for $X$ is similar. $\blacksquare$

In the proof above, what's the point of taking a bump function? If I know that $Y \equiv 0$ on $U$, which is a neighborhood of $p$, then isn't $\nabla_X |_{p \in U} Y \equiv 0$ trivially true?

Comment: What you're asking is tantamount to assuming the result to be proved, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection here is defined as a map of *global* sections, $\nabla\,\colon \mathfrak{X}(M)\times \Gamma(M,E)\to \Gamma(M,E)$, so the axioms a priori only tell you that $\nabla_X0 = 0$. In this proof, you'd like to say that if $Y\rvert_U = 0$ then $(\nabla_XY)\rvert_U = 0$, which is a statement about *local* sections. The role of the bump function is exactly to translate between them: we have $\varphi Y = 0$ on all of $M$, and the product rule, which is assumed on the level of global sections, lets you conclude.